# Solving Underdetermined Non-Linear Equation of Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, systems-of-equations, statistical-inference

I'm trying to see if I can solve for g in the set of linear equations:
$$ga+gb = m$$ $$ga+gb+2gab=n$$
where g, a, and b are all probabilities (i.e. between 0 and 1). I know that the problem is underdetermined, but I was wondering if through some clever algebra it is possible to get a unique solution for g or if there is a counterexample showing why it is not (i.e. two sets of g, a, and b that produce identical m and n). I tried squaring equation 1 and combining it with equation 2 to get (ga-gb) on one side of an equation, but that didn't work and I tried generating counterexamples from
$$gab = g'a'b'$$
$$ga+gb = g'a'+g'b'$$
But I can't seem to either definitively prove that g is or isn't universally solvable. My intuition (because it is an underdetermined set of equations) leads me to believe that it isn't... Thanks so much!

Comment: Take $m=n=0$. Equations are satisfied when $a=b=0$ regardless of $g$.

Comment: From the first equation, ag+ bg= m, we have for the second equation, m+ 2gab= n so 2gab= n- m, g= (n-m)/2ab.  Of course, that will not exist if either a or b is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several solution with the same $m$ and $n$. For example, taking
$(g,a,b)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},0)$ and $(g,a,b)=(\frac{1}{3},1,0)$ the equations are both times satisfied with $m=n=\frac{1}{3}$.

For an example with $0<g,a,b<1$, take $(g,a,b)=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5})$ and $(g,a,b)=(\frac{1}{4},\frac{9+\sqrt{21}}{30},\frac{9-\sqrt{21}}{30})$. Then both equations are satisfied with
$$
(m,n)=\left(\frac{3}{20},\frac{11}{60}\right).
$$